# React and Material-UI Autocomplete Multiple Items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui, formik

I have a problem with using `Formik` and `MUI` Autocomplete with multiple items.

For example: If you search by typing "Pencil", the issue is, it doesn't highlight it. Also you can still select it twice if you click it.

**Expected outcome:**
We would be able to select an item or items. When an item is selected, its checkbox would be selected, and it would be highlighted.

Here's my codesandbox: [CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/material-ui-centering-lwdzs6?file=%2Fsrc%2FtestApi.js%3A32%2C31&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr09imzx00063p6fmolclj5f%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr09imzx00023p6f88o7srwu%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr09imzx00033p6fw6bz0gyp%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr09imzx00053p6fv16blxcm%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B47.617218894768776%252C52.382781105231224%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clr09imzx00023p6f88o7srwu%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr09imzx00023p6f88o7srwu%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr09t0r800023p6f4zrey33y%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.tsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A16%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A7%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A16%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A7%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltuyo46i00023p6en976ka4j%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A32%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A31%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A32%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A31%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FtestApi.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltuyo46i00023p6en976ka4j%2522%257D%252C%2522clr09imzx00053p6fv16blxcm%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr09imzx00043p6fdduu8w8t%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr09imzx00053p6fv16blxcm%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clr09imzx00043p6fdduu8w8t%2522%257D%252C%2522clr09imzx00033p6fw6bz0gyp%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr09imzx00033p6fw6bz0gyp%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

```
const TestAutocomplete = ({
  field,
  form: { touched, errors, setFieldValue, values },
  ...props
}) => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const debouncedInputValue = useDebounceValue(inputValue, 500);

  const { data: response, isLoading } = useFetchSubledgersQuery({
    pageNumber: 0,
    pageSize: 50,
    search: debouncedInputValue,
  });

  const handleChange = (_, newSelectedValues, reason) => {
    if (reason === "clear") {
      setFieldValue(field.name, []);
      return;
    }

    setFieldValue(field.name, newSelectedValues);
  };

  const handleInputChange = (_, newInputValue) => {
    setInputValue(newInputValue);
  };

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      {...field}
      multiple
      getOptionLabel={(option) =>
        typeof option === "string" ? option : option?.name || ""
      }
      filterOptions={(x) => x}
      options={response || []}
      autoComplete
      includeInputInList
      fullWidth
      noOptionsText={isLoading ? "Loading..." : "No data"}
      onChange={handleChange}
      inputValue={inputValue}
      onInputChange={handleInputChange}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          {...props}
          error={touched[field.name] && errors[field.name] ? true : false}
          helperText={
            touched[field.name] &&
            errors[field.name] &&
            String(errors[field.name])
          }
        />
      )}
      renderOption={(props, option, { selected }) => (
        <li {...props}>
          <Checkbox
            icon={icon}
            checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
            style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
            checked={values?.[field.name]?.some(
              (selectedValue) => selectedValue.id === option.id
            )}
          />
          {option?.name}
        </li>
      )}
      renderTags={(value, getTagProps) =>
        value.map((option, index) => (
          <Chip
            key={option.id}
            label={option.name}
            {...getTagProps({ index })}
          />
        ))
      }
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: You never set `value` of the `Autocomplete`

Comment: @Konrad. I'm using formik's `name`

Comment: Can you clarify what "highlighting it" means exactly? I'm uncertain what any issue or problem is based on your description; I don't know what specifically you want us to focus on in the code or in the sandbox.

Comment: @DrewReese, the expected output is shown in this image: https://imgur.com/a/F0tc5Wx. You can select multiple items, and once they are selected, the checkbox will have a checkmark on it. However, the current issue is that when you type something and select it (https://imgur.com/a/TBlfiT6), there is a bug where you can select it more than once.

Comment: @DrewReese. This is the issue. https://streamable.com/m9i9pf

Answer (score -1, accepted):

De-duplicate the auto-complete's "new value" prior to updating the form state.

Example:

```js
const handleChange = (_, newSelectedValues, reason) => {
  if (reason === "clear") {
    setFieldValue(field.name, []);
    return;
  }

  const idSet = new Set();
  const deduplicated = newSelectedValues.reduce((values, current) => {
    if (!idSet.has(current.id)) {
      idSet.add(current.id);
      values.push(current);
    }
    return values;
  }, []);

  setFieldValue(field.name, deduplicated);
};
```

Override the default function that checks if options are equal to selected values using the `isOptionEqualToValue` prop.

```
<Autocomplete
  .... all other current props ....
  isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.id === value.id}
/>
```

Comment: It won't let me remove the check on its checkbox after you select it again. Also, the light blue background highlight isn't shown when it's currently selected. I have updated the code in my codesandbox.

Comment: @Joseph Yes, I think so.

Comment: I didn't downvote you. Your answer works well.